# Достаточно ли команды iostat -x чтобы оценить реальную нагрузку на диск?

Tags: linux, devops

Достаточно ли команды iostat -x чтобы оценить реальную нагрузку на диск?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать с ключом `iostat -xtc`
или :
`systat -iostat`,
`pidstat`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: iostat с параметрами -xtc можно оценить реальную нагрузку?